# Authorization error 401 using VB.NET to submit GET to REST API. Works fine in Access VBA

Tags: vb.net, rest, authentication

I am upgrading some code from VBA (Access) to VB.NET. The code is a simple HTTP GET on a REST API that is running on a PC on my LAN. Both code is running on the same Windows 7 PC. Access is 365 updated. Visual Studio is 2017.

Please use the link to get my short code. The two samples are only about 10 lines each.

This code works in Access VBA:

```
Dim httpReq As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Dim ServiceURLString As String

ServiceURLString = "https://Win7x64:10880/api/v2/companies"

httpReq.SetOption 2, httpReq.GetOption(2) - SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
httpReq.Open "GET", ServiceURLString, False, "user", "password"
httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
httpReq.send
ResponseText = httpReq.ResponseText
Debug.Print ResponseText
```

This code in VB.NET give error 401 Unauthorized on the **`request.GetResponse`**:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim url As String = "https://Win7x64:10880/api/v2/companies"
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
        request.Credentials = cred

        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
    End Sub

    Private Function AcceptAllCertifications(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
 End Class
```

Error Details

> System.Net.WebException HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=The remote server
>   returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

EDIT - Thank-you Dale for reformatting my post and guiding in how to do it.

Jimi:  I have made what I believe to be your intended edits and am still having the same issue.  Below is the code after those edits.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim url As String = "https://Win7x64:10880/api/v2/companies"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user" + ":" + "password")))

        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
        request.ContentType = "application/json"

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

    End Sub

    Private Function AcceptAllCertifications(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

EDIT 2
Well I have solved the problem but left with questions.  The code worked when I added a / character to the url.  I know now it's supposed to be there, since that endpoint in a list of elements but the original code did not have it and it worked fine. Perhaps that older serverXMLHTTP technology was more forgiving, and perhaps the API's reporting of errors is not perfect. This is not my API so I won't take it further now I can move on.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Did you try a network trace?

Comment: Not being familiar with that I had not thought of it.  I had not suspected that this was network related.  Same server, same PC running the two bits of code.

Comment: Yes, but you write no POST is accepted; so maybe check what the difference of the POSTs are, and whether something leaves the wire at all. At the beginning you talk about GET, BTW.

Comment: Yes it's a straight forward get with no request string at all.  My use of the word post was related to posting this question on this website.

Comment: Ok I understand how my text was misleading.   The word website did not refer to my API server, but the stackoverflow site.

Comment: For future reference https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: There are a number of things to correct here. It appears that this connection uses basic authentication. Add an authentication header to the **`HttpWebRequest`**: `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("userID" + ":" + "Password")));`. Move all related to the `ServicePointManager` on top of everything. Add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`. If the request requires a Token instead, substitute "basic " with "bearer " and add the Token instead of `User:Password`

Comment: The `HttpWebRequest` is in bold for a reason. Don't use `WebRequest/WebResponse`; cast to `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`. Those class appear to be the same but they're not. Note that you can add `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...)` in any case.

Comment: @Jimi Why not post as an answer. It's OK to earn a few reps once in a while for you considerable effort. After all someone has to surpass Jon one of these days. ;-)

Comment: Where did you add that slash (`/`) you're referrign to? I don't see it in code.

Comment: On the end of the URL.  I didn't update the post as Im not sure it's universal or if it's just my API misbehaving.  What I took away from this is that using different technologies can mean changing the url to make it work.  I had assumed that whatever method you used the url would be the same.  Lesson learned.